# Spring-boot compilation fail on Linux but ok on windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-compiler-plugin

I have created a brand new spring-boot project with version 3.1.1 of Spring-Boot and JDK 17. The project is shared on [github](https://github.com/tbasset-72/compile-bug-demo).

When i compile this project on windows, i have a build success. But if i try to compile the same project on Linux, the compilation fail with error :

```
Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
```

If i downgrade to spring-boot 3.0.8, the compilation works on Windows and on Linux.

I noticed Spring-boot 3.0.8 used maven-compiler version 3.10.1 while Spring-boot 3.1.1 used maven-compiler version 3.11.0.

A also noticed that spring-boot-parent version 3.0.8 has those properties :

```
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

While Spring-boot-parent hasn't those properties, but has :

```
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
```

My configuration are :

On windows :

- Windows 10
- OpenJDK 17.0..6.0.10
- Maven 3.9.1

On linux :

- AlmaLinux release 8.7
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.7.0.7-2)
- Maven 3.9.2

If i override the property maven.compiler.release with empty value in my pom.xml file, the compilation succeed.

Comment: Maven logs from my linux env are in the repos.

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments as that is totally unreadable. Run the compilation with `-e` or `-X` to get more information on why it fails and post that output in your question.

Comment: I can't (exceed limit of characters), but you can find the file on the github repository :  https://github.com/tbasset-72/compile-bug-demo/blob/master/compile_result.txt

Comment: Looks like another javac is used then you think. Try to find all occurences of javac and/or run `which javac` and check which one it is. Could be that there is one in the regular path that is taking precedence over the java version that has been installed and is on `java.home`.

Comment: Could be related ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36114

Comment: No that has nothing to do with this, that is documentation only.

Comment: Open a command window and type java -fullversion . That will  help you see which java you are actually running against.

Comment: javac was not found. Installing java-17-openjdk-devel.x86_64 on my Alma linux machine solve the problem. Nevertheless, i don't understand why everything works well with Spring-boot 3.0.x, but fails with spring-boot 3.1.x... Has anyone get an explanation ?